# Template for Cubicle Tags (Desk Tags) in LaTeX

Tags: templates

Does anyone have a good template for a `LaTeX` style cubicle or Desk Tags. The format of the tag can be as follows:

`Name` 
`Designation`
`Misc Info`

Comment: Could please you add a (maybe hand-drawn) sketch of how the tags should look.

Comment: Its no big pre-requisite that I was looking for just a square which contains `Name` `Designation` and `Misc Info` (such as email or phone number.) the template I feel would be similar to a visiting card.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some cool looking conference name tags [image: name tags]

And this is the code

```
%%%%
%
% ticket.sty example file for a pin for conferences
%
%%%%
% use the corresponding paper size for your ticket definition
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{letter}

% load ticket.sty with the appropriate ticket definition
\usepackage[freepin,crossmark]{ticket}

% load misc stuff
\usepackage{graphicx}

% make your default ticket. \ticketdefault is somewhat like a background
\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{%
  \put(55,  3){\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{tiger.eps}}
  \put( 5, 13){\line(1,0){60}}
  \put( 7, 10){\scriptsize Carolina Dynamics Symposium}
  \put( 7,  7){\scriptsize Clemson University}
  \put( 7,  4){\scriptsize April 13 -- April 15, 2012}
}

% now what do you like to put in your ticket
\newcommand{\confpin}[2]{\ticket{%
    \put(35,36){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries\Large #1}}
    \put(35,28){\makebox[0mm]{\bfseries\large #2}}%
}}


%% the pins for the partipiciants ... ;-)
%% you can generate this part from a database!
\begin{document}
\sffamily

\confpin{ Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}{Augusta State}
\confpin{ Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}{Augusta State}
\confpin{ Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}{Augusta State}
\confpin{ Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}{Augusta State}
\confpin{ Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}{Augusta State}
\confpin{ Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}{Augusta State}
\confpin{ Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}{Augusta State}
\confpin{ Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}{Augusta State}
\confpin{ Predrag Puno\v{s}evac}{Augusta State}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 because design and automation matter too, for those things. Having only two kinds of horizontal alignment (centred and left) seems more than enough for name tags.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems today is Predrag's day to replace all my half-answers with much better ones.

Comment: For me both the answers served the purpose but the later one by Predrag makes much more sense. Big thanks to both Mike and Predrag!

Answer (score 4):

There's a [flashcards](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flashcards) class on MiKTeX, TeX Live, and on CTAN that is originally for printing onto index cards, but section 4 of the documentation talks about adapting it for arbitrary card sizes. Section 2.3 shows how to print cards with an upper-left header, the main contents centered, and a lower-right footer.

Example:

```
\documentclass[custom-tags,fronts,frame]{flashcards}

\begin{document}
\cardfrontstyle{headings}
\cardfrontfoot{Footer}
\begin{flashcard}[Header]{Center}
This goes on the back of the card.
\end{flashcard}

\cardfrontfoot{Second Footer}
\begin{flashcard}[Second Header]{Second Center}
This goes on the back of the card.
\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

plus in custom-tags.cfg (copied from avery5388.cfg included with class):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\ProvidesFile{custom-tags.cfg}
\newcommand{\cardpapermode}{portrait}
\newcommand{\cardpaper}{letterpaper}
\newcommand{\cardrows}{4}
\newcommand{\cardcolumns}{1}
\setlength{\cardheight}{2.0in}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topoffset}{1.0in}
\setlength{\oddoffset}{0.25in}
\setlength{\evenoffset}{0.25in}

\endinput
```

produces:

[image]