# How to batch generate badges with a list of names?

Tags: printing, python, forms, scripts

I want to make a number of badges using LaTeX for the participants of a summer school. There are 40 or so people, so I don't want to manually change the name and compile and then print. I could think of:

1. Making a single document with a dropdown box with 40 choices. I don't know if it is possible to automate the choosing and printing in this case.
2. Using a script language such as python to call latex to do the job. But I have 0 experience with Python, and I didn't find a foolproof tutorial on the web (probably because of wrong search keywords).

So...I'm waiting for you guys to come up with a good solution :-).

Comment: You should search this side for "serial letter". This will give you some examples on how people are getting data from `.csv` and producing mutliple pdfs from it.

Comment: Probably `datatool` package provides some help

Comment: There's also `csvsimple`, which would surely be enough for this kind of task.  Would take the fun out of the answer below, however....

Comment: Related: [Template for Cubicle Tags (Desk Tags) in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14250/template-for-cubicle-tags-desk-tags-in-latex).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\def\Name{\expandafter\@firstoftwo\name}
\def\Affiliation{\expandafter\@secondoftwo\name}
\setlength\fboxsep{10pt}

\@for \name:=%
{{David}{here}},%
{{Paulo}{There}},%
{{egreg}{Somewhere}},%
{{Werner}{Not Here}},%
{{Gonzalo}{Not There}}%
\do {
\clearpage
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[c][4cm]{6cm}
Name: \Name\\
Afilliation: \Affiliation
\end{minipage}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is a good start. Is there an \affiliation too?I tried but failed.

Comment: @user74973 updated with two fields per name, more could be added as an exercise:-)

Comment: Wow,I really need to learn such techniques...is it something written in the texbook?

Comment: @user74973 `\@for` `\@firstoftwo` are defined in the latex format (so not in the texbook) The texbook of course describes the primitoves that define those commands.