# Printing a sheet multiple times with list of names

Tags: printing, content-replication

How to print the same exam (can be multiple pages long) multiple times with a different student name on it?

Something similar has been covered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191032/how-to-batch-generate-badges-with-a-list-of-names). However, I want the name list to be separated only with line break (like copy pasted from Google Drive or Excel):

```
Sam Student
John Doe
Bat Man
```

Comment: Have you looked at the datatool package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way using only one file, besides the list of students. In the example I used the `filecontents*` environment to make it self-contained.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{students.lst}
Sam Student
John Doe
Bat Man
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printexamtext}{m}
 {
  \ior_open:Nn \g_mappi_student_list_stream { #1 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_mappi_student_list_stream
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \studentname {##1}
    \mappi_print_exam:
   }
 }
\ior_new:N \g_mappi_student_list_stream
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mappi_print_exam:
 {
  \clearpage
  \setcounter{page}{1}
  \ExamHeader
  \BODY
  \ExamFooter
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff  

\NewEnviron{ExamText}[1]{%
  \printexamtext{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\ExamHeader}{%
  \begin{center}
  \LARGE Linear Algebra -- 2014 -- Fall Session \\[2ex]
  \large \studentname
  \end{center}
  \vspace{2cm}
}

\newcommand{\ExamFooter}{%
  \vfill
  \hrule
  \vspace{2ex}
  \noindent Please, answer all questions\par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{ExamText}{students.lst}
\noindent\textbf{Exercise 1}

Compute the rank of a matrix of your choice.

\bigskip

\noindent\textbf{Exercise 2}

What are the eigenvalues of the identity matrix?

\bigskip

\noindent\textbf{Exercise 3}

Prove that the zero matrix is not invertible.
\end{ExamText}

\end{document}
```

The `ExamText` environment contains the questions, type it as if it were a normal document. I split up the header and footer to have them in a separate place (for code reusing).

[image]

`xparse` is not really necessary, it just makes it easier to loop through an external file.

Comment: Works like a glove! And, aww, how sweet of you to provide questions as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Shamelessly based on the code in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199529/).

I would use `textmerg`. In combination with `titling` and `fancyhdr`, you don't need to do anything special to get the examination title etc. customised for each student's paper. The use of `enumitem` makes it easy to customise the format of the questions if this is desired.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{students.lst}
  Sam Student
  John Doe
  Bat Man
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textmerg,titling,fancyhdr,enumitem,kantlipsum}
\newlist{examqns}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[examqns]{label=Question \arabic*, font=\bfseries, wide, ref=\arabic*}

\begin{document}
  \title{Introduction to Philosophy --- Autumn 2014}
  \date{Date of Examination}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhf[lh]{\thetitle}
  \fancyhf[cf]{\theauthor}
  \fancyhf[rh]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}

  \Fields{\studentname}
  \Merge{students.lst}{%
    \clearpage% use \cleardoublepage if printing double-sided
    \author{\studentname}
    \maketitle
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \begin{center}
      \fbox{\parbox{.5\linewidth}{%
          \centering\bfseries
          \large Answer ALL questions.\\
          \normalsize There are \ref{lastone} questions.\\
        }}
    \end{center}
    \bigskip

    \begin{examqns}
        \item Could this examination have been a surprise?
        \item Prove God's existence. (Maximum 250 words)
        \item Why does Russell's barber present a problem?
        \item \label{lastone}Critically evaluate the following passage from Kant:
        \begin{quote}
            \kant[1-3]
        \end{quote}
    \end{examqns}
  }

\end{document}
```

[image: examination]

Comment: My questions are more difficult. :P

Comment: @egreg Yes, but the answers to mine are harder :).